# Java library for writing raw audio into a compressed OGG file

Tags: library, java, audio

Is there a Java library for taking a raw audio stream and saving it as a .OGG file with a decent compression ratio?

In particular, I'm using the [Java Beads Project](http://www.beadsproject.net/), open open-source tool for sound synthesis. It has a built-in tool for writing its audio to WAV files, but not to any other format. I would like to create my own class to write to a OGG file so that I have an option for compressing my generated audio.

The interface I have for saving an audio file provided by Beads is the [`AuddioFileWriter`](https://github.com/orsjb/beads/blob/master/src/beads_main/net/beadsproject/beads/data/audiofile/AudioFileWriter.java) interface, which looks like this:

```
public interface AudioFileWriter {

    /**
     * Single method to write an entire audio file in one go.
     * @param data - the data to be written
     * @param filename - the name of the file to be written
     * @param type - the type of audio file to be written (mp3, wav, etc.)
     * @param saf - a SampleAudioFormat object specifying the attributes of the sample data to be written. Can be NULL, in which case default values will be used.
     */
    public void writeAudioFile(float[][] data, String filename, AudioFileType type, SampleAudioFormat saf) throws IOException, OperationUnsupportedException, FileFormatException;

    // snip    
}
```

So I have the raw audio in a `float[][]`. Each sub-array of the data is one channel, and each array contains an amplitude level for each frame of audio. So I need to save the audio represented by the `float[][]` to OGG and save that. If I need to, I'm willing to do some simple bit-twiddling to get the `float[][]` into a different format that an OGG library expects.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution: https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava